# Flutter, background services and tasks are not working on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, background-service

I run a background service in Flutter and make this service listen to the Connection state with the help of Connectivity and if there is a connection, I send data to the server. It works properly even if I terminate the application on Android, but as soon as I terminate it on iOS, the service closes, is there any way to run the service continuously?

Answer (score 0):

IOS has lifecycle policies that can result in background services or execution being killed but you can find a work around. Plugins allow using callbacks and a callback dispatcher to handle background events. You would have to implement this for each specific platform (Android/IOS). Adding the code snippet would've been great but this is a good place to start [Background Processes - Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/background-processes). Also check this for how background tasks work in IOS  [Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks) . Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already checked them these are like an alarm manager only triggers with duration I guess there is no chance of making what I want on iOS. Thanks again.